# How to connect digital piano with plug and play?

Tags: music, midi

I'd like to connect my old Korg c-15s digital piano to my Toshiba Satellite laptop using a plug and play cable (midi > usb).
I have never done this before, tried a few tutorials but couldn't seem to succeed.
I'm not interested in using the piano as a midi controller or anything fancy, just record it using Audacity or some other similar software.

Here some information.

System Devuan Chimaera kernel 5.10.0-21-amd64
alsa and alsa-utils installed
qjackctl installed
audacity installed
This is a screenshot of what appears on qjackctl connections where I assume 0:CH345 MIDI 1 is the piano interface.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MFI60n_M_eSQ8aj9vF-01mGYWjJ5u-22/view?usp=share_link

here's some more information

```
$ aseqdump
Waiting for data at port 129:0. Press Ctrl+C to end.
Source  Event                  Ch  Data

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5652 IMC Networks TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a86:752d QinHeng Electronics CH345 MIDI adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ lsmod | grep usb
snd_usb_audio         319488  2
snd_usbmidi_lib        45056  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_rawmidi            45056  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_usbmidi_lib
mc                     61440  5 
videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
snd_hwdep              20480  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               143360  11 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_compress,snd_pcm_oss,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core
usbcore               331776  5 
xhci_hcd,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,uvcvideo,xhci_pci
snd                   110592  29 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,  snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_pcm_oss,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_mixer_oss
usb_common             16384  3 xhci_hcd,usbcore,uvcvideo

$ aconnect -i
client 0: 'System' [type=kernel]
0 'Timer           '
1 'Announce        '
client 14: 'Midi Through' [type=kernel]
0 'Midi Through Port-0'
client 20: 'CH345' [type=kernel,card=1]
0 'CH345 MIDI 1 

$ lshw
        *-multimedia
         description: Audio device
         product: Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio 
Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1b
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
         version: 0e
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
         resources: irq:95 memory:d0810000-d0813fff
```

Thanks for any pointers or suggestions.

Comment: As far as visible from your lsusb, the keyboard can only be used as midi controller! If you record something with that, you need synthesizer software that takes these midi events and makes tones from them.

Comment: Could you suggest some such software that's easy to use?

Comment: [Rosegarden](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rosegarden/) seems to be suitable. Check your distribution for a package.

Comment: I'm really not a musician, so I have no clue what "easy" means, but I think the standard is musescore (which I think is a fair bit less "dusty" than rosegarden).

Comment: I do have musescore3 installed.I tried to configure it to use the midi input with qjackctl but it doesn't seem to work.